# Update Maven Dependencies Jars

Tags: maven, jar, jboss

I am new to Maven and have a quick question. I am using the JBoss IDE and have my Maven project set up. I have several jar files in my Maven Dependencies build path that need to be updated to a newer version. I have tried adding the external jars manually, but they do not go within the Maven Dependencies library and the outdated jar remains within that library.

What is the best way to update the jars with the Maven Dependencies library?

Comment: You have to update the versions of the appropriate libraries in your pom.xml file...

Comment: @khmarbaise some of the jars are not within the pom.xml, for example I have the com.thoughtworks.xstream jar as part of the build path, but it is not included within the pom.xml

Comment: It is strongly recommended to put _all_ dependencies in the `pom.xml` and not use other means to put artifacts on the build path.